# What is the opposite of explosive decompression?

Tags: pressure, air

Is it something like "implosive compression"? Cannot find the correct term.

Explosive decompression is when the pressure rapidly drops, e.g. spaceship gets a hole and passengers cannot breathe; I'm looking for a coined term for when the pressure rapidly rises, e.g. deep sea submarine gets a hole underneath and the air inside is compacted towards its ceiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe (damaging something by suddenly applying a large *overpressure*) is how bombs kill people and destroy buildings. On the human body this is called concussive shock. In the case of bombs this is called blast damage.

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually call it an *implosion*.